# C# EntityFramework IQueryable Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We're seeing memory resources not be released:

[image]

With the following code using .NET Core:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {          
            var testRunner = new TestRunner();
            testRunner.RunTest();
        }
    }
}

public class TestRunner {
    public void RunTest() {
        using (var context = new EasyMwsContext()) {
            var result = context.FeedSubmissionEntries.Where(fse => TestPredicate(fse)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public bool TestPredicate(FeedSubmissionEntry e) {
        return e.AmazonRegion == AmazonRegion.Europe && e.MerchantId == "1234";
    }
}
```

If I remove the test predicate `.Where` I get a straight line as expected, with the predicate the memory will continue to rise indefinitely.

So while I can fix the problem I'd like to understand what is happening?

EDIT:

Altering the line to:

```
public void RunTest() {
    using (var context = new EasyMwsContext()) {
        var result = context.FeedSubmissionEntries.ToList();
    }
}
```

Gives the graph:
[image]

So I don't believe this is due to client side evaluation either?

EDIT 2:

Using EF Core 2.1.4

And the object heap:
[image]

Edit 3:

Added a retention graph, seems to be an issue with EF Core?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you know how the garbage collector works, why do you think it's a problem? Have you run it to the point where you get problems? What were those, did you get out-of-memory exceptions?

Comment: IQueryable doesn't leak because it doesn't *do* anything. It represents a query that hasn't executed yet. The code itself though creates a lot of termporary objects. `Where(fse => TestPredicate(fse))` is suspicious though - this can't be translated to SQL unless the compiler *inlined* `TestPredicate`. You may be loading the entire database in memory for filtering without realizing it.

Comment: 1) Which EF Core version are you using 2) Take two memory snapshots in the diagnostics window and check which objects result in that memory increase. 3) EF Core [brings back client-side evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) . It's optional but on by default. [You can disable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation) with `.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));` in the DbContextOptionsBuilder

Comment: 1 is important. Anything before 2.2 (preview) is known to be buggy as hell with no real fixes coming. Heck, anything before 3.0 will not get any major LINQ rework, and that IS a piece that regularly blows.

Comment: Even if you create temporary string variables in an infinite loop, eventually you get out-of-memory exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up running into the same issue. Once I knew what the problem was I was able to find a bug report for it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13048) in the EntityFrameworkCore repository.

The short summary is that when you include an instance method in an `IQueryable` it gets cached, and the methods do not get released even after your context is disposed of.

At this time it doesn't look like much progress has been made towards resolving the issue. I'll be keeping an eye on it, but for now I believe the best options for avoiding the memory leak are:

1. Rewrite your methods so no instance methods are included in your `IQueryable`
2. Convert the `IQueryable` to a `list` with `ToList()` before using LINQ methods that contain instance methods (not ideal if you're trying to limit the results of a database query)
3. Make the method you're calling `static` to limit how much memory piles up

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the culprit isn't a memory leak but a rather unfortunate addition to EF Core, [Client Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation). Like LINQ-to-SQL, when faced with a lambda/function that can't be translated to SQL, EF Core will create a simpler query that reads *more* data and evaluate the function on the client.

In your case, EF Core can't know what `TestPredicate` is so it will *read every record in memory* and try to filter the data afterwards.

BTW [that's what happened](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1047929955206795267) when SO moved to EF Core last Thursday, October 4, 2018. Instead of returning a few dozen lines, the query returned ... 52 million lines :

```
var answers = db.Posts
                .Where(p => grp.Select(g=>g.PostId).Contains(p.Id))
                ...
                .ToList();
```

Client evaluation is optional but on by default. EF Core logs a warning each time client evaluation is performed, but that won't help if you haven't configured EF Core logging.

The safe solution is to *disable* client-side evaluation as shown in the [Optional behavior: throw an exception for client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation) section of the docs, either in each context's `OnConfiguring` method or globally in the Startup.cs configuration :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(...)
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => 
                           warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
}
```

**UPDATE**

A quick way to find out what's leaking is to take two memory snapshots in the Diagnostics window and check what new objects were created and how much memory they use. It's quite possible there's a bug in client evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited main question - it's a very small table for testing so I don't believe it's due to client side evaluation?

Comment: @NickSpicer use memory snapshots in the diagnostics window to check what new objects are created. In any case, it's EF Core that loads the data, not IQueryable. You may have found a real leak in client evaluation. Which EF Core version did you use? Such bugs are version-specific

Comment: Yep apologies, it also errors when preventing client side evaluation so can confirm it's definitely going that route. Edited the main ticket.